# Getting football(soccer) videos without channel name on the top or any sort of layout

Tags: editing

So i am trying to edit a montage for football so i trying to get some videoa to work with but all I can find are videos with layouts which doesn't look good in the video and I think with layouts it may get me in some trouble beacuse of the copyrights so i would appreciate it if anyone could tell me how to find videos withou channel names or stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

Finding sport events video without any copyrights attached will be a difficult task. (Like there are none).

So, actually, you cannot (as in you are not allowed to) make your own sport event video by using copyrighted videos and either finding them without marks or removing these marks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for, is called "feed".